# IIS Sites Randomly Become Inaccessible

Tags: iis, coldfusion, 503-error

Server Config:

Windows Edition: Server 2012 R2 Standard (with most recent updates)
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz (2 processors)
System type: 64-bit OS, x64-basd processor

In IIS, I have 1 FTP site that is publicly accessible, 5 websites that are publicly accessible, and 1 website that is accessible only on the server (via 127.0.0.1). The 6 websites are all running with ColdFusion as the server software. Each website runs in its own Application Pool.

Four of the public websites read and write data to and from an external IBM DB2 database. The other public website reads and writes data to and from a local SQL Server database.

The problem: At random times, any one of the websites will suddenly become inaccessible, responding with a 503 HTTP Status Code. When this happens, all the other websites are up and running fine. Executing "iisreset" in Command Prompt always resolves the issue.

These websites are not heavily trafficked. In fact, sometimes an outage will happen in the middle of the night when there is next to no traffic. I can't for the life of me figure how or why this is happening. I need some help with where to look and what to look for in order to permanently resolve this.

Comment: Check your server logs.

Comment: 1) SQL Server and IIS on the same machine is never a good setup, as the two compete with each other for memory usage. 2) Instead of using `iisreset`, try to manually recycle the application pools to see whether the sites can be back to normal. That can indicate what might be wrong. 3) Also set up a static test site there with its own application pool, so that you can use it to test whether it is a general IIS issue or ColdFusion issue. 4) Windows event log should have something recorded, as the other comment indicated.

Comment: @LexLi THanks for this. 1) I know SQL Server on the same server is not the best setup, but my options were limited (I'm more a developer than sys admin, which is why I'm here for help). I will make it a priority to move. 2) I do iisreset because it's quick and easy, and sometimes it's more than one website. If I recycle the app pool and the site comes back up, what does this tell me? 3) I know for a fact it's not a CF issue because the other CF sites function normally during a site outage. 4) What should I look for in the server logs?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm seeing the same, exact, issue on Windows 2019 and ColdFusion 2018.

Comment: @PMascari I have not found a cause to the issue, but as a workaround solution, i setup a Scheduled Task to reset IIS each day very early in the morning when traffic is minimal.